# Traducción de "update" o "status"

Tags: traducción

Estoy pensando en poner "actualización".

Contexto: un oficio al cliente acerca de un trámite legal de papeles.

Comment: "actualización" me parece suficiente, pero "update" y "status" no son sinónimos. Uno sería "actualización" y el otro algo así como "estado" o "situación actual".

Comment: @aparente001: una opción puede ser: `estado de su trámite legal`. Considero que cuando no existe una palabra que exprese lo que se intenta decir, es mejor usar algunas palabras de la frase para hacer énfasis.

Comment: "Estatus" con "e" inicial te sirve. Pero es preferible "estado".

Comment: @Rodrigo, yo aceptaría tu aportación si hicieras una Respuesta.

Comment: Qué interesantes comentarios y qué ganas de verlos convertidos en respuestas Va, va, que queremos subir la "answer ratio" http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bajo el contexto que comentas, ya fuese un correo electrónico, un sello o un sistema informático, yo te aconsejaría que utilizaras algo como: **Estado del oficio Nº [número] - [Aprobado/Recibido/En curso/Denegado]**. Luego donde creas conveniente, podrías especificar la fecha de ese estado como: **Última actualización : [fecha de hoy]**

Si fuese un proceso manual y no informático en donde estés haciendo uso de un sello o escritura a mano podrías simplemente omitir **Estado del oficio** y escribir el estado actual del oficio.

Por ejemplo:

> **En proceso / Recibido**
>
> Notario Juan Perez
>
> [Código de notario]
>
> Firma
>
> [Fecha de hoy]

Answer (score 1):

Si estás preguntando acerca de cual es el estatus de algo como es común en ingles:

> What is the update/status for this task/process/activity?

Si a esto te refieres, podría ser:

> Cual es el estado actual/ultima actualizacion de la tarea/actividad/proceso, etc.

Es necesario conocer un poco mas del contexto para dar una respuesta mas apropiada.

Answer (score 1):

### Status:

It can be translated as:

- **1 - Estatus:**

> (From English Status, and this Lat. Status, state, condition).
>
> 1. Position a person occupies in society or in a social group.
> 2. Relative position of something within a certain framework. The status of a concept within a theory.

[Definición de "Estatus", en la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=estatus)

Synonymous of **hierarchy**, in Latin would be: ***status quo***.

- **2 - Estado:**

[Definición de "Estado", en la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=pC94RxX11DXX2RnEnFA1)

---

### Update:

It can be translated as:

- **1 - Actualizar:**

> 1. Make today something, give today.
> 2. Updating data, standards, prices, rents, wages, etc.
> 3. Put into action, performing.
> 4. Get the current value of a future payment or income.
> 5. Make abstract or virtual linguistic elements become concrete and individual.

[Definición de "Actualizar", en la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?fw=actualizar&o=h)

- **3 - Mejorar:**

> 1. Overtaking, increase something by passing to a better state.
> 2. Get better, to regain lost health.
> 3. In a tenderer: Increase the price put something offered for sale, auction, etc.
> 4. Leave improvement testament to one or more of the heirs.
> 5. Go recovering lost, restored health.
> 6. This time: Put more favorable or benign.
> 7. Put in place or advantageous degree in respect of which previously had.

[Definición de "Mejorar", en la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=mejorar&m=form&o=h)